# How can I make a Multiple property lambda expression with Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I use

```
ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");

var myexp=Expression.Lambda<Func<T, TKey>>(Expression.Property(parameter, "myid"), parameter);
```

to create a lambda expression myexp like this

```
p=>myid
```

now I wanna create a mult property like this

```
p=> new {myid,myid2}
```

Comment: You can just write the lambda you're trying to create and look at it in a debugger to see what expressions it's using, so that you know what you need to create, specifically.

Comment: Follow this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/12705338/763026

Comment: @Servy I write it for generic class,need to handle propertyName to change

Comment: @JohnTiXor Okay.  That doesn't change my point.

Comment: I think you mean `p => p.myid`.

Comment: You can't create anonymous type at runtime. It's unclear what are you trying to achieve - what will be the type of the result, how it's supposed to be used etc.

Comment: You can actually create anonymous types at runtime, but it is rarely worth it.

Comment: @Ivan Stoev  actually I can, I use List<T>.AsQueryable().GroupBy(p=>new{p.myid,p.myid2}).Select(p => p.First()) to replace dinstinct(IEqualityComparer<T>),if I can handle expression "p=>new{p.myid,p.myid2}",then no need to repeat create IEqualityComparer anymore. it's also useful to make dynamic query with combination expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tricky part of doing this is accessing the anonymous type's type so you can call `new` for it. I normally use LINQPad to create a sample lambda and dump it to see the format:

```
Expression<Func<Test,object>> lambdax = p => new { p.myid, p.myid2 };
lambdax.Dump();
```

Assuming the type of `p` is `Test`:

```
class Test {
    public int myid;
    public int myid2;
}
```

Then you can create `Expression`s to recreate the `lambdax` value:

```
var exampleTest = new Test();
var example = new { exampleTest.myid, exampleTest.myid2 };
var exampleType = example.GetType();

var rci = exampleType.GetConstructors()[0];
var parm = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Test), "p");
var args = new[] { Expression.PropertyOrField(parm, "myid"), Expression.PropertyOrField(parm, "myid2") };

var body = Expression.New(rci, args, exampleType.GetMembers().Where(m => m.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property));
var lambda = Expression.Lambda(body, parm);
```

Comment: I tried LINQPad and love it, thanks help alot ^ ^,now I use object type to pass anonymous type to do what I want!