# Select only specific fields with Linq (EF core)

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a `DbContext` where I would like to run a query to return only specific columns, to avoid fetching all the data.
The problem is that I would like to specify the column names with a set of strings, and I would like to obtain an `IQueryable` of the original type, i.e. without constructing an anonymous type.

Here is an example:

```
// Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.All
// Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore

using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Person {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class TestContext : DbContext {
    public virtual DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    public TestContext(DbContextOptions<TestContext> options) : base(options) {
    }
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {

        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TestContext>();
        builder.UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        var context = new TestContext(builder.Options);

        context.Persons.Add(new Person { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" });
        context.SaveChanges();

        // How can I express this selecting columns with a set of strings? 
        IQueryable<Person> query = from p in context.Persons select new Person { FirstName = p.FirstName };
    }
}
```

I would like to have something like this method:

```
static IQueryable<Person> GetPersons(TestContext context, params string[] fieldsToSelect) {
    // ...
}
```

Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: Use reflection. It's going to get ugly and messy and you'll have a performance penalty, but other than mapping each property to a string, it's probably the only way.

Comment: Even using reflection, how could I create the select statements? What I want to avoid is to fetch all the data from the DB.

Comment: Use raw sql then map into your own DTO. We did that in the past. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can do this, Google Search "Dynamic Linq" this might get you on the right tracks, also take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16516971/linq-dynamic-select

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Since you are projecting (selecting) the members of the type `T` to the same type `T`, the required `Expression<Func<T, T>>` can relatively easy be created with `Expression` class methods like this:

```
public static partial class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> SelectMembers<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, params string[] memberNames)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "e");
        var bindings = memberNames
            .Select(name => Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, name))
            .Select(member => Expression.Bind(member.Member, member));
        var body = Expression.MemberInit(Expression.New(typeof(T)), bindings);
        var selector = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T>>(body, parameter);
        return source.Select(selector);
    }
}
```

[Expression.MemberInit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.memberinit?view=netframework-4.7.2) is the expression equivalent of the `new T { Member1 = x.Member1, Member2 = x.Member2, ... }` C# construct.

The sample usage would be:

```
return context.Set<Person>().SelectMembers(fieldsToSelect);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. I was trying to do something like that based on this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701737/expression-to-create-an-instance-with-object-initializer) but I got lost on the `Lambda` bit :)

Comment: How do you achieve this in anonymous projections?

Comment: @Wendell As mentioned in the beginning, this approach is applicable only for projecting into the same type. Now with your comment looks like `T` cannot be anonymous type if that's what you mean. I have to admit the code doesn't work with anonymous types.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by using [Dynamic Linq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/).

and for .Net Core - [System.Linq.Dynamic.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/)

With Dynamic Linq you can pass in your SELECT and WHERE as a string.

Using your example, you could then do something like:

```
IQueryable<Person> query = context.Persons
                        .Select("new Person { FirstName = p.FirstName }");
```

Comment: Please give an example how this can be achieved by using Dynamic Linq

Comment: The OP has tagged the question as .NET Core, this package is ~3 years old now and is probably just targeting full .NET.

Comment: There are Dynamic Linq for .Net Core too, I've updated my answer to include a link to the .net Core Nuget library

Comment: Thanks. I tried this out but I couldn't find the correct syntax for the select clause.

Comment: would be interesting how the performance is, compared to a self build solution using expression trees

Answer (score 1):

Based on [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54550068/3845726) of [Ivan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5202563/ivan-stoev) I made crude version of caching function to eliminate the toll layed on us by using of reflexion. It allow as to lower this toll from **milli**seconds to **micro**seconds on repeated requests (typical for DbAccess API, for example).

```
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> SelectMembers<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, IEnumerable<string> memberNames)
    {
        var result = QueryableGenericExtensions<T>.SelectMembers(source, memberNames);
        return result;
    }
}


public static class QueryableGenericExtensions<T>
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, ParameterExpression> _parameters = new();
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, MemberAssignment> _bindings = new();
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, Expression<Func<T, T>>> _selectors = new();

    public static IQueryable<T> SelectMembers(IQueryable<T> source, IEnumerable<string> memberNames)
    {
        var parameterName = typeof(T).FullName;

        var requestName = $"{parameterName}:{string.Join(",", memberNames.OrderBy(x => x))}";
        if (!_selectors.TryGetValue(requestName, out var selector))
        {
            if (!_parameters.TryGetValue(parameterName, out var parameter))
            {
                parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), typeof(T).Name.ToLowerInvariant());

                _ = _parameters.TryAdd(parameterName, parameter);
            }

            var bindings = memberNames
                .Select(name =>
                {
                    var memberName = $"{parameterName}:{name}";
                    if (!_bindings.TryGetValue(memberName, out var binding))
                    {
                        var member = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, name);
                        binding = Expression.Bind(member.Member, member);

                        _ = _bindings.TryAdd(memberName, binding);
                    }
                    return binding;
                });

            var body = Expression.MemberInit(Expression.New(typeof(T)), bindings);
            selector = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T>>(body, parameter);

            _selectors.TryAdd(requestName, selector);
        }

        return source.Select(selector);
    }
}
```

Example of results after sequential run with same params (please note that this is NANOseconds):

```
SelectMembers time ... 3092214 ns
SelectMembers time ... 145724 ns
SelectMembers time ... 38613 ns
SelectMembers time ... 1969 ns
```

I have no idea why the time decreases gradually, not from "without cache" to "with cache", may be it is because of my environment with loop of questioning 4 servers with same request and some deep-level magic with asyncs. Repeating request produces consistent results similar to the last one +/- 1-2 microseconds.

Answer (score 1):

My answer based on [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54550068/22817151) of [Ivan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5202563/ivan-stoev) and on [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67356841/22817151) of [orchic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3845726/ornic).

I wrote a [nuget library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SmartSelector).

Installation:

```
dotnet add package Kurnakov.SmartSelector
```

Code example:

```
IQueryable<Person> query = context.Persons
    .SelectFields(new List<string>() { "FirstName", "LastName" });
```

More details you can find [here](https://github.com/kurnakovv/SmartSelector)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
string fieldsToSelect = "new Person { FirstName = p.FirstName }"; //Pass this as parameter.

public static IQueryable<Person> GetPersons(TestContext context, string fieldsToSelect) 
{
    IQueryable<Person> query = context.Persons.Select(fieldsToSelect);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this with the package https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core so easily.

Here is an example code.

use namespacing, `using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core;`

```
//var selectQuery = "new(Name, Id, PresentDetails.RollNo)";

var selectQuery = "new(Name, Id, PresentDetails.GuardianDetails.Name as GuardianName)";

var students = dbContext.Students
    .Include(s => s.PresentDetails)
    .Include(s => s.PresentDetails.GuardianDetails)
    .Where(s => s.StudentStatus == "Admitted")
    .Select(selectQuery);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var students = dbContext.Students
    .Include(s => s.PresentDetails)
    .Where(s => s.StudentStatus == "Admitted")
    .Select(p => new Person() 
                       { 
                           Id = p.Id, 
                           Name = p.Name
                       });
```

Why not minimize the selected columns in the regular way? this is way cleaner.

Comment: In the question, I said that I want to specify the column names with a set of strings :)